# Bootstrap MultiSelect Options list need to hide while scroll the window

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="example">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#multi-select-demo').multiselect();
    });
</script>
<select id="multi-select-demo" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="jQuery">jQuery tutorial</option>
    <option value="Bootstrap">Bootstrap Tips</option>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="CSS">CSS tricks</option>
    <option value="angular">Angular JS</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In multiselect, we have a bunch of options. These options need to hide while user scrolls the window. The list is contained in a `ul` with class name "multiselect-container".

Comment: did you mean closing the dropdown when user scrolls?

Comment: yes, it is @semira

Comment: any possible solution or this @semira

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a click outside the element should do the trick.

`$(document).click();`

There is no official way to 'close' the bootstrap dropdown, however, the above one is a workaround to handle that. It basically triggers a fake click outside the dropdown, therefore, closing it.

**If you want it to close every time user starts scrolling, then:**

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $(document).click();
});
```

Comment: this is not a possible solution for given issue.

Comment: can you share the running example with this code please

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://codepen.io/zdo/full/MWgmPbd for Code, see https://codepen.io/zdo/pen/MWgmPbd

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('.nav');

$window.on('scroll', function(){
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
@import bourbon

body
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif
  height: 8000px

.nav
  background: #111
  text-align: center
  color: #fff
  +padding(20px null)
  +position(fixed, null 0px 0px 0px)
  +transition(transform 1s $ease-in-out-quint)

.nav.hidden 
  +transform(translateY(100%))
    
p
  margin: 0
  +padding(20px)
```

```html
<div class="nav">Scroll to show/hide this bar!</div>

<p>They see me scrolling...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
          rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="example">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#multi-select-demo').multiselect();
            });

            window.addEventListener("wheel", myScript);

            function myScript() {
                $("#multi-select-demo").dropdown('toggle');
            }
        </script>
        <select id="multi-select-demo" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="jQuery">jQuery tutorial</option>
            <option value="Bootstrap">Bootstrap Tips</option>
            <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
            <option value="CSS">CSS tricks</option>
            <option value="angular">Angular JS</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```